# In Apache Airflow, how can I get the results of a "SELECT" statement on a Google Cloud SQL Database?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-sql

I need to retrieve data from a Google Cloud SQL database in one of my Dags.

I tried using the CloudSqlQueryOperator (https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/gcp_sql.html) but my SELECT queries are not working. Is there a way to retrieve data from a select query on Google Cloud SQL from Airflow?

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Are you getting any error? What error? You need to share the code which is having this error.

Answer (score 2):

The [query operator](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator.CloudSqlQueryOperator) does "not return any data from the database, so it is useless to pass it DQL queries".

You may or may not want to use the [export operator](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator.CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator) instead, depending on