# How to retrieve data into Airflow DAG from Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-sql

I want to retrieve data into airflow DAG (data is not huge, 3 columns for maybe 6 rows max) from Cloud SQL, which is in another project.

so Project A has Composer/Airflow
Project B has Cloud SQL

**There is a VPC network extending both projects**. So that's not my current problem.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332360/in-apache-airflow-how-can-i-get-the-results-of-a-select-statement-on-a-google) But it says to export data into Cloud Storage, but how to import that data back into DAG then?

I searched some things on the internet but am unsure if it is correct.
Example 1.
Below MySqlOperator only seems to be able to execute DDL or DML queries.

```
from datetime import datetime   
from airflow import DAG   
from airflow.providers.mysql.operators.mysql import MySqlOperator
```

Documentation: [Example 1 Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/operators.html)

**I tried Bing Copilot and Chat GPT too, But they are giving inconsistent responses, so I am wondering if it is possible to get data into DAG.
As Airflow is designed to orchestrate not handle data.**

Comment: I didn't catch your issue. Are you trying to connect Composer to your Cloud SQL instance in the projectB? Are you trying to get the exported data (in a GCS bucket) into a new step in Airflow? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve date from Cloud SQL into Composer DAG and use it further. 1. I'm not able to find the correct Operator in Airflow for this retrieval. 2. If exported to GCS bucket, then how to retrieve that bucket's data into the same DAG?

Comment: If you need to retrieve a date, use a query in your database. If you need data in a Cloud Storage, get the data from there. But I think you issue is to pass value from one step to the other. For that you can use Xcom. There is a good article here: https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/exchange-data-between-tasks-in-airflow-xcom-d32a02da21a3